# How does SMB2 protocol map a filename to a unique File ID when transferring files?

Tags: network-protocols, smb

I am doing the SMB2 protocol parsing. When using WireShark to capture packets I find that the file name contained in **Create Request** is replaced by File ID in **Create Response** and subsequent communication. I want to know how to map the file name to File ID, or how to locate the file name via FIle ID. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can compare with Posix primitives. After fopen(0 what you have is a file handle rather than a file name. To recall the name you need to consider one of the previous lines of the code - the context. This is exactly how Wireshark works. It matches a response with the respective request and saves the name associated with the ID.

If you have only ID and no name, you can query file information over SMB and the server will respond with a file name.